# javascript delete and update html content with counter

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```js
let milestoneCount = 2;
function addNewMilestone() {
    milestoneCount++;
    let newMilestone = `
        <div class="form-box" id="milestone${milestoneCount}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <h4 class="form--title">Milestone ${milestoneCount} <i class="fa fa-times" id="x-button" onclick="removeMilestone(${milestoneCount})"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location">${getOrdinalNumber(milestoneCount)} Milestone Name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="milestone_name" placeholder="Enter a milestone name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
    let rowsContainer = document.getElementById('rowsContainer');
    rowsContainer.innerHTML += newMilestone;
}
function removeMilestone(milestoneId) {
    let milestoneElement = document.getElementById(`milestone${milestoneId}`);
    milestoneElement.remove();
    if (milestoneId === milestoneCount) {
        milestoneCount--;
    }
}
function getOrdinalNumber(n) {
    const suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
    const remainder = n % 100;
    const suffix = suffixes[(remainder - 20) % 10] || suffixes[remainder] || suffixes[0];
    return `${n}${suffix}`;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button onclick="addNewMilestone()">Add</button>

<div id="rowsContainer"></div>
```

what it is supposed to do is add the `newMilestone` code to the `rowsContainer` div, which it does. however, the problem is that when I go to delete it via the 'x' button here: `<i class="fa fa-times" id="x-button" onclick="removeMilestone(${milestoneCount})"></I>`

it doesn't work as I would like it. what I expect to happen is for example, I add 3 milestones, so I have milestone 1,2,3,4,5 (1 and 2 are hardcoded). then, if I go to delete milestone 4, I should now see 1,2,3,4, not 1,2,3,5, which I what I currently get. I cannot figure out how to fix it! Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If not, can you comment what else you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Your numbered items are not going to renumber themselves when you delete one. You need to do that part yourself. First of all, let me suggest not using ID attributes at all. There's no need.

For your delete, I recommend using relative paths with [element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the item to remove:

```
 onclick="removeMilestone(this)"
```

Then your function

```
function removeMilestone(el) {
    el.closest('.form-box').remove();
    renumberItems()
}​
```

The `renumberItems()` function is separated so you can call it from anywhere, but it basically does this

```
function renumberItems() {
  let n = 1;
  document.querySelectorAll('.form-box').forEach(e => {
     e.querySelector('.form--title').textContent = `Milestone ${n}`;
     e.querySelector('label[for=location]').textContent = `${getOrdinalNumber(n)} Milestone Name *`);
     n++;
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean "`id`" attributes? — not tags.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, dynamic IDs are more of a hassle than they are worth.

For my answer, I'm also delegating the click handler to the document.body so it isn't inline.

I gave the delete button a class so I can refer to it in the click handler. I also wrapped your mile stone number in a span so I can change it again.

Then in the click handler, I reset the counter to 2. I remove the row from the DOM then just loop through the form rows and replace the milestone name wit the appropriate name from your function.

```js
let milestoneCount = 2;
function addNewMilestone() {
    milestoneCount++;
    let newMilestone = `
        <div class="form-box" id="milestone${milestoneCount}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <h4 class="form--title">Milestone ${milestoneCount} <i class="fa fa-times btnDelete">DELETE</i></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location"><span class='mileStone'>${getOrdinalNumber(milestoneCount)}</span> Milestone Name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="milestone_name" placeholder="Enter a milestone name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
    let rowsContainer = document.getElementById('rowsContainer');
    rowsContainer.innerHTML += newMilestone;
}

function getOrdinalNumber(n) {
    const suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
    const remainder = n % 100;
    const suffix = suffixes[(remainder - 20) % 10] || suffixes[remainder] || suffixes[0];
    return `${n}${suffix}`;
}

addNewMilestone();
addNewMilestone();
addNewMilestone();
addNewMilestone();

document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.classList.contains("btnDelete")){
    el.closest(".form-box").remove();
    milestoneCount = 2;
    let forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form-box")
    forms.forEach((f) => {
      milestoneCount++;
      f.querySelector(".mileStone").textContent = getOrdinalNumber(milestoneCount)
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="rowsContainer"></div>
```